# Laravel routing: error 404 because of routes order

Tags: laravel

I have the following routes:

```
Route::get('/crear_cuenta', [RegisterController::class, 'index'])->name('register');
Route::post('/crear_cuenta', [RegisterController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index'])->name('login');
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'store']);
Route::post('/logout', [LogoutController::class, 'store'])->name('logout');

Route::get('/{user:username}', [PostController::class, 'index'])->name('posts.index');
Route::get('/posts/create', [PostController::class, 'create'])->name('posts.create');
Route::post('/posts', [PostController::class, 'store'])->name('posts.store');
Route::get('/{user:username}/posts/{post}', [PostController::class, 'show'])->name('posts.show');
Route::delete('/posts/{post}', [PostController::class, 'destroy'])->name('posts.destroy');

Route::post('/{user:username}/posts/{post}', [CommentController::class, 'store'])->name('comments.store');

Route::post('/imagenes', [ImageController::class, 'store'])->name('images.store');

Route::post('/posts/{post}/likes', [LikeController::class, 'store'])->name('posts.likes.store');
Route::delete('/posts/{post}/likes', [LikeController::class, 'destroy'])->name('posts.likes.destroy');

// Rutas para el perfil
Route::get('/editar-perfil', [ProfileController::class, 'index'])->name('profile.index');
Route::post('/editar-perfil', [ProfileController::class, 'store'])->name('profile.store');
```

When I access /editar-perfil I get an error 404. If I move the /editar-perfil routes up the issue stops.

```
Route::get('/crear_cuenta', [RegisterController::class, 'index'])->name('register');
Route::post('/crear_cuenta', [RegisterController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index'])->name('login');
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'store']);
Route::post('/logout', [LogoutController::class, 'store'])->name('logout');

// Rutas para el perfil
Route::get('/editar-perfil', [ProfileController::class, 'index'])->name('profile.index');
Route::post('/editar-perfil', [ProfileController::class, 'store'])->name('profile.store');

Route::get('/{user:username}', [PostController::class, 'index'])->name('posts.index');
Route::get('/posts/create', [PostController::class, 'create'])->name('posts.create');
Route::post('/posts', [PostController::class, 'store'])->name('posts.store');
Route::get('/{user:username}/posts/{post}', [PostController::class, 'show'])->name('posts.show');
Route::delete('/posts/{post}', [PostController::class, 'destroy'])->name('posts.destroy');

Route::post('/{user:username}/posts/{post}', [CommentController::class, 'store'])->name('comments.store');

Route::post('/imagenes', [ImageController::class, 'store'])->name('images.store');

Route::post('/posts/{post}/likes', [LikeController::class, 'store'])->name('posts.likes.store');
Route::delete('/posts/{post}/likes', [LikeController::class, 'destroy'])->name('posts.likes.destroy');
```

Why is that? I'm guessing it has something to do with the routes that contain {user:username} but I don't know why.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I know that I've come late to the party, but this is a very good question and it deserves a detailed answer.

Laravel routes offer a feature called [model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-model-binding), and the idea behind it is really simple:

> When injecting a model ID to a route or controller action, you will often query the database to retrieve the model that corresponds to that ID. Laravel route model binding provides a convenient way to automatically inject the model instances directly into your routes. For example, instead of injecting a user's ID, you can inject the entire User model instance that matches the given ID.

For example, take the following route definition:

```
Route::get('users/{user:username}', function(App\Models\User $user) {
    dump($user);
});
```

In this case, you're injecting the username of the user, so when you try to visit the route `users/john.doe` Laravel will try to retrieve the `User` model that has the username `john.doe`, and if it fails to do so it will respond with an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` exception, sending a 404 HTTP response.

Now let's go back to your example:

```
Route::get('/{user:username}', [PostController::class, 'index'])->name('posts.index');

// Rutas para el perfil
Route::get('/editar-perfil', [ProfileController::class, 'index'])->name('profile.index');
Route::post('/editar-perfil', [ProfileController::class, 'store'])->name('profile.store');
```

When you try to visit the `editar-perfil` route, Laravel will try to resolve a user model that has a username field with the value `editar-perfil` because the `posts.index` route will always be matched by Laravel, and any other GET route that consists of a single segment (like `editar-perfil`) will never be reached, that's why moving it to the top helped you solve the problem because you gave it a higher priority to be matched.